# Firebase Cloud Function, triggers onWrite method and getting problem in retrieving user data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

[This is the cloud function that triggers when data is changed,created or deleted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTPRA.png)
Inside this function i have marked the code, in which i want to retreive the user token that is stored in another node of real time database with same id.As you can see in the real time database. But i am unable to fetch the token from the database. Kindly help me to fix this problem.

[This is Structure of my realtime database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br0lQ.png)
 i want to get the token from the database in this cloud function

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code **within the question itself**.  Links to code might go stale over time, which would render this question useless to others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise, but you don't wait this Promise resolves in order to get the value of the node.

Since you declare your Cloud Function as an async function, the following should do the trick

```
//...
const deviceTokenSnap = await admin.database().ref(`tokens/${userId}/token`).once('value');
const token = deviceTokenSnap.val();
//...
```

---

In addition it is recommended to avoid mixing the use of async/await an `then()`.

You should adapt the end of the function as follows:

```
const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...);
console.log(response);
return null;
```

---

You should also use a try/catch block, see https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a

---

Finally, please avoid adding screenshots of your IDE, but copy/paste the code to your question.